# Pandas how to create groups of continuous batches (time series data)

Tags: python, pandas, sklearn-pandas, data-wrangling

I have a time series of data that I need to create batches of N for training.
For instance for batches of 3, need rows `[0, 1, 2]` labeled as  `[1, 1, 1]`, `[3, 4, 5]` labeled as `[2, 2, 2]`, `[6, 7, 8]` as `[3, 3, 3]`.

Sample Data:

```
   Diff  N_Bars
0 -2.17    22.0
1  4.13    48.0
2 -0.65     4.0
3  2.06    59.0
4 -2.07    11.0
5  0.68     8.0
6 -0.43     2.0
7  1.21    19.0
8 -0.39     9.0
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? And could you please show an example output so we can see the desired structure of your data (multiindex, cat, interval...)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to replace the index and don't mind the duplicates, you can simply set a new index with `index // n_per_group + 1` (floor division):

```
n_per_group = 3
df.index = df.index // n_per_group + 1
```

**Advantage**: You can index by the batch label.
**Disadvantage**: Duplicates in the index will probably cause some trouble.

---

Instead of replacing the index, you can of course also set this to a new row:

```
n_per_group = 3
df['batchlabel'] = df.index // n_per_group + 1
```

**Advantage**: No duplicates in the index.
**Disadvantage**: Indexing by the batch label has to be done indirectly with f.i. `df[df['batchlabel'] == 2]`.

### Recommended solution:

---

But the **best way** would be to create a `MultiIndex` with the batches in level 0 and the old indices in level 1. This way you avoid having **duplicates** but are still **able to index by the batch number.**:

```
n_per_group = 3
# create multiindex
new_midx = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays((df.index //  n_per_group  +  1, df.index))
# assign multiindex
df_midx = df.set_index(new_midx)

# index by batch number:
df_midx.loc[2]
# Out:
   Diff  N_Bars
3  2.06    59.0
4 -2.07    11.0
5  0.68     8.0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this :

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

n=3 #batches of 3
df=pd.DataFrame({"A":np.random.rand(10),"B":np.random.rand(10)})
df["index"]=df.index
df["label_batches"]=df["index"].apply(lambda x : x//n)
```